# Iterating pandas dictionary with if, elif, else clause for sql query execution

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm using pandas dictionary in order to execute multiple sql statements.
Example dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'ETL_A': ['TABLE_001', 'TABLE_002', 'TABLE_003'],
            'TEST1': ['TABLE_TEST', 'TEST001', 'SAMPLE_TEST'],
            'TEST2': ['TABLE_TEST2', 'TEST2', 'SAMPLE_TEST2'],
            'MY_PRIVATE_SHEMA': ['WWW_001', 'LTT_222']}
```

my code:

```
my_schema = 'ETL_A'
my_table = 'TABLE_001'
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

for schema, tables in my_dict.items():
    for table in tables:
        if my_schema is None:
            timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            query = f"CREATE TABLE {schema}.{table} SELECT * FROM {schema}.{table} at(timestamp => '{timestamp}'::timestamp);"
        else:
            if schema == my_schema:
                query = f"CREATE TABLE {my_schema}.{table} SELECT * FROM {my_schema}.{table} at(timestamp => '{timestamp}'::timestamp);"

cur.execute(query)
```

In my code I'm using variables my_schema, my_table... I would like to execute multiple queries based on my defined variables. So in case if I don't have ddefined variables so if my_schema = None I would lime to execute query for all schema names and tables. Same thing with case when my_table = None so if it's not defined. Based on my needs I wold have defined variables such as my_schema and my_table and if I have defined just my_schema = 'TEST1' I expect to have query only for this schema and all tables. If I have my_schema = 'TEST1' and my_table = 'TABLE_TEST' I expect to have query only for this schema and table. If all variables are None I expect to have query for all schema and tables.

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error message? Show it in question (not in comments) as text. Do you get wrong query? Show wrong query and expected query.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: as for you should run `for`-loop inside `if/else` instead of running `if/else` inside `for`-loop

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you want to make a conditional iteration over all the schemas on your dictionary.
To do that, I would perform the following:

```
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

my_dict = {'ETL_A': ['TABLE_001', 'TABLE_002', 'TABLE_003'],
           'ETL_TEST': ['TABLE_001', 'TABLE_002', 'TABLE_003']}

def run_over_tables(tables):
    for table in tables:
        query = f"CREATE TABLE {schema}.{table} SELECT * FROM {schema}.{table} at(timestamp => '{timestamp}'::timestamp);"
        cur.execute(query)

def main(schema):
    if schema:
        tables = my_dict[schema] # list of tables
        run_over_tables(tables)
        return
    for schema in my_dict.keys():
        tables = my_dict[schema]
        run_over_tables(tables)
    return
```

Comment: I would need without function.

Comment: @My80 you can always copy code from function `run_over_tables` into place where it is executed - and you will have it without function. But this will need to repeate the same code in two places and code will be less readable.